# Oracle multiple join query from same table, is displaying duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Using an **Oracle 11g DB**, I am looking for a way to consolidate two rows from one table into a single row on my query result, but also allow NULL values where data has not been entered.

Basically I have something like:

TABLE1 contains object identification

TABLE2 contains two rows for object data (type A & B)

I was thinking I'd need to run an OUTER JOIN, which works when only getting object data type A, but when when I add a second JOIN, I get multiple repeated lines of A for each line of B.

So if there are 4 A values and 5 B values, I will see 5 rows of A for each row of B (20 rows in total)

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T2a.VALUE as TYPE_A, T2b.VALUE as TYPE_B 

FROM TABLE1 T1

LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2a ON (T1.ID = T2a.ID AND T2a.TYPE='A')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2b ON (T1.ID = T2b.ID AND T2b.TYPE='B')
```

I'm wanting to get this (see how A has 6 entries, B has 5):

```
NAME    TYPE_A      TYPE_B

ID1     VALUE1      VALUE2
ID1     VALUE1      VALUE2
ID1     VALUE1      (NULL)
ID1     VALUE1      VALUE2
ID1     (NULL)      VALUE2
ID1     VALUE1      (NULL)
ID1     (NULL)      VALUE2
ID1     VALUE1      (NULL)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

KS

Comment: Don't you have any other join in your query? Are you certain that `ID` are unique in their respective tables ?

Comment: Seems to me you just want to pivot the data on type...

Comment: ID1 is the same in this example, with the data for TYPE_A and TYPE_B being different. Basically we have a product(s) which can have two types of test. the tests are on separate rows (A & B) I need to 'merge' these into a single row: product, testA, testB.  LEFT JOIN gets me the data, but I get duplicate rows, so if there are 5 testA and 6 testB, I seem to get 30 rows (one testA row for each testB)

Answer (score 0):

Would a Pivot work?

Note Pivot only works if you know all the values of Type that you want.  If it's not known, then you have to use dynamic SQL..

```
SELECT *
FROM  
(
  SELECT Name, Type, Value
  FROM   Table1 T1
  INNER JOIN table2 T2 
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Value)
  FOR (Type) IN ('A' AS TYPE_A,
                 'B' AS Type_B)
);
```

Comment: Can a WHERE be put into this for WHERE name = 'XYZ'?

Comment: I don't see why not. It could occur in two different places depending on where we want the limit to be imposed.  Before data is pivoted, or after.  if before simply add where after the on clause.  If after, add where clause after last ) and before ;.

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` should work here

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46004f/2

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT T1.ID, T2.type, T2.value
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID) 
PIVOT
( MAX(value) FOR type in ('A', 'B')
)
```